# redirect example.com to example.com/index.html in S3 Cloudfront setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting, website-hosting

I set up s3 bucket and CloudFront setup for hosting example.com following this blog: https://simpleit.rocks/web/hostings/redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www-with-aws-s3-bucket-cloudfront-route-53-and-a-custom-domain/

Http to Https; www to non-www; all works as expected.

Now, Is there a way to redirect https://example.com/index.html to https://example.com ?
Because SEO analyzer showing example.com & example.com/index.html as duplicated pages

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You usually want to do the opposite and redirect `/index.html` to `/`.   There is no reason to have `index.html` in any of your URLs.  The purpose documents with that name is to provide content that powers the directory level URL.  Having `index.html` in the URL is bad for usability and bad for SEO.  You shouldn't ever link to `index.html` from the rest of your site.

Comment: Ok. Make sense. How to get example.com/index.html to example.com?

Comment: updated question.